# Como gerar uma subcategoria a partir da seleção anterior? Combobox

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de Gestão de pessoas. Nele possuo um formulário html para a inserção de alguns dados. Preciso separar os cargos em seus respectivos setores, ou seja o setor será a categoria e os cargos subcategorias.

Abaixo o código com a seleção dos setores:

```
<select name="grava_colaborador_setor" name="grava_colaborador_setor" class="form-control">
<option value="">Selecione</option>
<?php
$result_cat_post = "SELECT * FROM tb_setores";
$resultado_cat_post = mysqli_query($mysqli, $result_cat_post);
while($row_cat_post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_cat_post) ) {
echo '<option value="'.$row_cat_post['id_setores'].'">'.$row_cat_post['nome'].'</option>'; }? </select>
```

Abaixo está a estrutura da tabela. Preciso separar as categorias conforme o setor selecionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A tabela não está normalizada.. a relação é: Um cargo pode pertencer a vários setores. Da maneira que você estruturou a tabela você acaba repetindo a informação do cargo. Eu faria 3 tabelas: cargo, setores, níveis.

Comment: Mas eu preciso amarrar o setor ao cargo, eu quero apenas o valor no formulário para trazer na subcategoria os cargos conforme a ID do setor.

Comment: Você precisa primeiramente carregar 1 drop-down com os setores, e depois através de um script em ajax, realizar a carga de forma dinâmica dos cargos que pertencem à um setor, para isto terá que escrever um script à parte que só traga os elementos do segundo drop-down (cargos) através de um parâmetro que indique o setor. Veja exemplos aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611277/populating-a-dropdown-list-in-php-dynamically